# Grouping data based on their values

Tags: php, grouping

I want to group and display data (numbers) comma separated in cells in an html table. I want to group data based on their values. So if there are numbers between 1-20, they would be in the first column like `6,10,11,12,15,17`.  How can I achieve this easily? Thank you.

My code is like this:

```
   <table class="tbstyle">
        <tr>
        <th>1-20</th> 
        <th>21-40</th>
        <th>41-60</th>
        <th>61-80</th>
        <th>81-100</th>
        </tr>

        <?php

          include ("config.php");   
          $sql = "SELECT Rpa, Rpb, Rpc, Rpd, Rpe, Rpf, Rpg, Rph, Rpi, Rpj, Rpk, Rpl, Rpm, Rpn, Rpo, Rpp, Rpq, Rpr FROM RpDb";
          $result = $conn->query($sql);
          if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
           while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
           {

//I am stuck in this part.  

           }  
              echo "</table>";

        } else { echo "0 results"; }
        $conn->close();
            ?>   

        </table>
```

Comment: you are repeating `Rpk, Rpl, Rpk, Rpl,` in your SELECT

Comment: please clarify _"there are numbers between 1-20"_ - this numbers are the values of `$row['Rpa']`? And you want also Rpp in the first column if its <=20?

Comment: What do you want to do with the `Rpf` to `Rpr` values?

Comment: Loop on your results and compare each result with your limits (1-20, 21-40, ...).  Build a string variable for each group, with the values you got from the database.  Once all results are sorted, then display the `<tr><td></td></tr>` elements.  Ex: `if (($result >= 1) and ($result <=20)) { $one_twenty = "$one_twenty, $result"; }`.  Later you do `echo "<tr><td>1..20</td><td>$one_twenty</td></tr>\n";`

Comment: Sorry, the above code what I did, but it doesn't give the result i want clearly. Each field name has one data/number and it can be any value.

Comment: I  removed the echo part which was not correct to clarify the problem.

Comment: So how do you want to fill the other columns?

Comment: ok just to clarify as this is mildy confusing, you want to get the array values from all of the columns, sort the array low-high and then split the array every 20 values for every row?

Comment: yes, that is right.

Comment: All columns will be filled in the same way. if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a relatively simple solution using [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$rows = array(
    array(1, 30, 40, 22, 12, 14, 55, 68, 91, 80, 99, 23, 63, 61, 83),
    array(8, 17, 59, 14, 93, 31, 57, 91, 29, 38, 54, 47, 28, 12, 15)
    );

// replace this line with your while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    sort($row);
    $groups = array_reduce($row, function ($c, $v) { $c[(int)floor(($v-1) / 20)][] = $v; return $c; }, array());
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        echo "<td>" . implode(',', isset($groups[$i]) ? $groups[$i] : array()) . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Output:

```
<tr><td>1,12,14</td><td>22,23,30,40</td><td>55</td><td>61,63,68,80</td><td>83,91,99</td></tr> 
<tr><td>8,12,14,15,17</td><td>28,29,31,38</td><td>47,54,57,59</td><td></td><td>91,93</td></tr>
```

Comment: I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' error in this line:        echo "<td>" . implode(',', $groups[$i] ?? array()) . "</td>";

Comment: Sorry I assumed you were running PHP7. My bad. Change `groups[$i] ?? array()` to `isset($groups[$i]) ? $groups[$i]  : array()`

Comment: @Max Also just realised I was using `intdiv` which is PHP7 too. I have updated my answer with PHP5.x compatible code. Sorry about wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code snippet that does what I think you want to acomplish. There might be quicker ways (with less loops), but it does it's job.

```
<?php

$borders = [20,40,60,80];
// some test data
$rows[] = ["Rpa" => 30, "Rpb" => 14, "Rpc" => 1, "Rpd" => 24];
$rows[] = ["Rpa" => 41, "Rpb" => 33, "Rpc" => 20, "Rpd" => 79];


$grouprows = []; // we'll need some array to re-structure your rows.
foreach($rows as $row) { // this is your while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    $groups = []; // the former columns will be packed into "groups" (1-20, 21-40,..)
    foreach($row as $column => $value) {  // walk through all Rpa, Rpb, ...
        foreach($borders as $i => $border) {   // walk through the borders (<20, <40, <60,..)
            if($value <= $border) {  // if it fits into the current group/border, add it to that group
                $groups[$border][] = "$column: $value";
                break;  // ..and don't look any further
            }
        }
        ksort($groups);  // sort the groups to be ascending
    }
    $grouprows[] = $groups;  // add the just edited row to the main array
}

// actual output
echo "<table border=1>
        <tr>
        <th>1-20</th> 
        <th>21-40</th>
        <th>41-60</th>
        <th>61-80</th>
        <th>81-100</th>
        </tr>";

foreach($grouprows as $row) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    $colcount = 0;
    foreach($row as $col) {

        if(is_array($col)) {
            echo "\t<td>" . implode(", ",$col) . "</td>\n";
        } else {
            echo "\t<td></td>\n";
        }
        $colcount++;
    }
    // if we haven't filled all column yet (because there were no fitting values), add empty tds
    for($colcount;$colcount<count($borders);$colcount++) {
        echo "\t<td></td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n"; 
}
echo "</table>";
```

A snippet: https://3v4l.org/SFPBW

Output:

```
<table border=1>
        <tr>
        <th>1-20</th> 
        <th>21-40</th>
        <th>41-60</th>
        <th>61-80</th>
        <th>81-100</th>
        </tr>
<tr>
    <td>Rpb: 14,Rpc: 1</td>
    <td>Rpa: 30,Rpd: 24</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Rpc: 20</td>
    <td>Rpb: 33</td>
    <td>Rpa: 41</td>
    <td>Rpd: 79</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Jeff, thanks, I'm trying to understand your code, but it doesn't give me the correct output.  Sample output for <th>1-20</th> can be like 6,10,11,12,15,17 in the same cell. and for  <th>21-40</th> can be like 22,23,24,30,31,33.

Comment: then just remove the `$column: ` and make the line `$groups[$border][] = $value;`

Answer (score 1):

Ok so based on my understanding of your question you want to fetch all numbers(data's) from all of your columns in your database and order them into your table, so this is an example on how to do this:-

```
...
$num_list = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
       foreach ($row as $value)
           array_push($num_list, $value);

//sort the numbers
sort($num_list);

//insert them into the table
for($i=1; $i<=100; $i+=20){
    $res = "";
    //store the numbers between these indexes into this string
    foreach($num_list as $value)
        if($value >= $i && $value < $i+20)
            $res .= $value . ", ";
    //remove the end comma
    if(strlen($res) != 0)
        $res = substr($res, 0, -1);
    //echo the data
    echo "<td>$res</td>\n";
}
...
```

> Edit

I don't understand this speaking **I want to group and display data (numbers) comma separated in cells** because you said in the comment below that you don't want the values comma separated in a single cell, So I try to divide the results into the rows **but without separating them by comma or anything else**, So let's try to do some changes in my code before inserting `for loop`:-

```
...
$all_values = array();

//insert them into the table(old comment)
//insert them into the array(new comment)
for($i=1; $i<=100; $i+=20){
    //insert an array into the array
    array_push($all_values, array());
    //store the numbers between these indexes into this array
    foreach($num_list as $value)
        if($value >= $i && $value < $i+20)
            array_push($all_values[count($all_values)-1], $value);
}

//Getting the count of the longest group of numbers and sorting them
$longet_length = 0;
foreach($all_values as $value){
    sort($value);
    if(count($value) > $longet_length)
        $longet_length = count($value);
}

//Finally insert them into the table
$current_index = 0;
while($current_index < $longet_length){
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach($all_values as $value)
        if(count($value) > $current_index)
            echo "<td>{$value[$current_index]}</td>\n";
        else
            echo "<td>Empty</td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";

    $current_index++;
}
...
```

Comment: I don't want to insert all the numbers of a column in a cell. The values of each row are grouped into five columns between the specified ranges. Your code puts all the data in a column into a single cell.

Answer (score 1):

this has been untested and off the cusp, however the base logic of what i think you're trying to achieve is there. Let me know if there's any issues and i'll amend the answer.

```
$row_nums = array_values($row);
asort($row_nums);

$grouped_scores = [];

foreach($row_nums as $num){

    switch (true) {
      case  ($num <= 20):
        $grouped_scores[1][] = $num;
        break;
      case  ($num > 20 && $num <= 40):
        $grouped_scores[2][] = $num;
        break;
      case  ($num > 40 && $num <= 60):
        $grouped_scores[3][] = $num;
        break;
      case  ($num > 60 && $num <= 80):
        $grouped_scores[4][] = $num;
        break;
      case  ($num > 80):
        $grouped_scores[5][] = $num;
        break;
    }

}

echo '<tr>';

foreach($grouped_scores as $score_array){

    echo '<td>'.implode(',', $score_array).'</td>';
}

echo '</tr>';
```